# My sum var isn't serving as a container as hoped

Tags: python, scope, turtle-graphics

I've written this code to perform two sequences: 1--draw a recursive display of triangles, staying inside the bounding box, and returning the sum of all painted area; 2-- repeat iteratively

I believe there is a scope issue, for the reason of 'sum' not working. However, I don't know how I could get the turtle to stay in his box, without changing his randomly generated distance and angle.

```
import turtle
import random
import math

def BOUNDING_BOX():
    #creates a bounding box
    turtle.up()
    turtle.setpos(-200, -200)
    turtle.down()
    turtle.fd(400)
    turtle.left(90)
    turtle.fd(400)
    turtle.left(90)
    turtle.fd(400)
    turtle.left(90)
    turtle.fd(400)
    turtle.left(90)
    turtle.up()
    turtle.setpos(0, 0)

def arrowRecur(quan, sum):
    if quan == 0: # main() blocks negatives
        #base case
        return sum
    else:
        #recursive call
        curr_sum = drawTri()
        turtle.fd(MAX_DISTANCE())
        turtle.right(MAX_ANGLE())
        sum += curr_sum
        arrowRecur(quan - 1, sum)


def arrowIter(quan, sum):
    while quan > 0:
        curr_sum = drawTri()
        turtle.fd(MAX_DISTANCE())
        turtle.right(MAX_ANGLE())
        sum += curr_sum
        quan -= 1
    else:
        return sum


def main():
    #initializes program
    sum = 0
    quan = int(input("Enter in the quantity of triangles (0-500): "))

    if 0 > quan or quan > MAX_FIGURES():
        raise ValueError("Invalid Input: Execution Terminated")
    else:
        turtle.colormode(255)
        BOUNDING_BOX()
        sum = arrowRecur(quan, sum)
    print("Our total painted area is ",sum," units.")
    input("Press ENTER to continue to iterative version.")

main()
```

Comment: Edit your question to include only the relevant sections of your code or the simplest example that illustrates your problem. Not many people are willing to sift through 109 lines of code to diagnose the issue.

Answer (score 1):

If you can write this code, you should be able to debug it! Why didn't you debug this yourself? For future questions, you should follow these guidelines:
[Are there legitimate "fix my code" questions?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/253787/are-there-legitimate-fix-my-code-questions)

Specifically: "The troubleshooting steps you've attempted so far to isolate the problem."

For the sum problem, two things:

```
>>> 1/2
0
```

so this line computes an area of 0:

```
return ((1/2)*base*height)
```

and in the recursion, you are not updating the value of sum:

```
arrowRecur(quan - 1, sum)
```

should be

```
sum = arrowRecur(quan - 1, sum)
return sum
```

To get the turtle to stay in the box, you will need to add more code to check that it's coordinates never exceed the edges of the box.